# How do you create a string literal in excel?

Tags: excel

I have the following which needs to go into excel:

```
MovieID
-eodII2h
```

However, when I type it in, excel tries marking this up as a formula, and gives me:

```
#NAME?
```

Is there a way that I can skip the normal excel formatting on a cell, or if not, how to do a string literal in a cell?

Comment: When you type "-eodII2h" it reads the "-" as "minus", and tries to initiate a mathematical formula. Since there is no name defined as "eodll2h" it doesn't know how to proceed. To correct this, precede your text with an '.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put a simple quote before the minus sign, like:
'-eodllH

Comment: strangely, that doesn't work if i'm entering the cells from CSV: `'-` literally shows up in the cell as `'-` instead of `-`.

Comment: check if there isn't any space before the quote.
right: ['-    ]
wrong: [    '-]