# Pandas to_csv now not writing values correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, data-science

I'm using to csv to save a datframe which looks like this:

```
    PredictionIdx   CustomerInterest
0   fe789a06f3  0.654059
1   6238f6b829  0.654269
2   b0e1883ce5  0.666289
3   85e07cdd04  0.664172
```

in which I've a value '0e15826235' in first column.I'm writing this dataframe to csv using pandas to_csv() . But when I open this csv in google excel or libreoffice it shows 0E in excel and 0 in libreoffice. It is giving me problem during submission in kaggle. But one point to note here is that when I'm reading the same csv using pandas read_csv it shows the above value correctly in dataframe.

Comment: since it shows correctly in dataframe then the is no problem from the library side. it  should be because of editor.  try using  `df.to_excel()`

Comment: what error do you get from kaggle? could you post a sample of the faulty csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the first comment, the error is resulting from your choice of editor. Many editors will use some version of scientific notation that reads an `e` (in specific places like the second character) as an indicator of an exponent. Excel, for instance, will read it as a "base X raised to the power Y" where X are the numbers before the `e` and Y are the numbers after the `e`. [This is a brief description of Excel's scientific notation.](https://exceljet.net/lessons/how-to-use-scientific-formatting-in-excel)

This does not happen in the other cell entries because there appear to be other string-like characters. Excel, Libre, and possibly Google attempt to interpret what the entry is, rather than taking it literally.

In your question you write '0e15826235' with single quotes, indicating that it might be a string, but this might be something to make sure of when writing out the values to a file -- Excel and the rest might not know this is meant to be a string literal.

In general, check for the format of the value and consider what your eventual editor might "think" it is when it opens. For Excel specifically, a single quote character at the start of the string will force Excel to read it as a string. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853682/how-do-you-create-a-string-literal-in-excel).

Comment: Indeed you are right! The editor does not interpret as a string literal. Also, if I save my file after that in that editor then that literal gets changed to its wrong value interpreted earlier by the editor. It can be seen directly if we open it in text editor as csv

Answer (score 0):

For me code below works correctly with google spreadsheets:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'PredictionIdx': ['fe789a06f3',
                                     '6238f6b829',
                                     'b0e1883ce5',
                                     '85e07cdd04'],
                   'CustomerInterest': [0.654059,
                                        0.654269,
                                        0.666289,
                                        0.664172]})

df.to_csv('./test.csv', index = None)
```

Also csv is very simple text format, it doesn't hold any information about data types.
So you could use `df.to_excel()` as Nihal suggested, or adjust column type settings in your favourite spreadsheets viewer.